# Problema con las URL - http://localhost/index.php/admin funciona http://localhost/admin no

Tags: php, mvc

Estoy dando mis primeros pasos en programación.... Ahora estoy pasando un proyecto a Model view controller...

Tengo problemas con las URL.... he leído días y no le encuentro la vuelta... seguramente es configuración del servidor pero no logro dar con la tecla.

Necesito capturar las url...
Pero si coloco en el navegador localhost/admin no lo encuentra en el servidor (not found)...
Si coloco localhost/index.php/admin logro capturar la url. Y $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] me indica que la url es '/admin'

Mi httpd está de la siguiente manera.

```
#LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
#LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so

DocumentRoot "C:/laragon/www/Atenea_MVC/public"
<Directory "C:/laragon/www/Atenea_MVC/public">

Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
```

El método con el que intento obtener la URL solo funciona si coloco index . php entre localhost y las carpetas....

```
$router -> get('/admin' , [PropiedadController::class , 'index']);
$router -> get('/propiedades/crear' , [PropiedadController::class , 'crear']);
$router -> get('/propiedades/actualizar' , [PropiedadController::class , 'actualizar']);
```

Estuve leyendo sobre htaccess pero sinceramente no he entendido como solucionarlo....

Estoy muy perdido....

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que si no tienes configurado tu `htacces`  para que ignore la extensión, tu servidor siempre interpretará `/admin` como si fuera una carpeta en la cual hay un archivo index y por eso si es que colocas `index.php/admin` si funciona ya que el archivo es `index.php` y la ruta es `/admin`
Para ignorar la extensión **php** haces lo siguiente en tu *htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```